# Entity Framework 4.1 Connection to external DB fail

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I want to connect to an external DB.
And I checked the connection when I added the connection string, it's ok.
However, when I run the program, it said "Login fail for my account".

Anyone know what's happening?

Thanks!

EDIT, connection string:

```
      connectionString="Data Source=server_of_th_db;Initial Catalog=the_DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Comment: Did you checkedd the provided credentials, and also paste the exception info.

Comment: We need more details: can you connect to the DB using a DBMS (i.e Sql Server Management Studio)?

Comment: @Shai yes, I can connect to that DB using DQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Can you show us your connection string?

Comment: @Shai Connection string is posted above.

Comment: Is your project split into multiple C# projects? If yes, is your connectionstring in the app.config of the application that is set as your Startup project?

Answer (score 2):

probably, you don't want to use `Integrated Security=SSPI;` which means the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.
You probably have to specify `User Id` and `Password` to be able to connect to the remote server. like:

```
connectionString="Data Source=server_of_th_db;Initial Catalog=the_DB;Uid=MY_USER_ID;Pwd=MY_PASSWORD;"
```

You'd have to get these credentials from the dba of that server.

*Update:*
Another possible issue is that you're using the wrong .config file. If there are multiple projects in your solution, make sure the `connectionstrings` section of the start up project is set appropriately.

Comment: I tried the code above, however the error still exist. I want to use SQL authentication, but the error returned said Login fail for my windows account